# Open a method implementation in another project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have two separate Eclipse projects; I am simply building a Jar (that does not have a source attachment) from the first project that is referenced in the second one's build properties. The first project holds the interfaces or abstract classes for implementation classes that reference them in the second project.

When I control-click on a method in the first project and choose 'open implementation', it shows me the first project's interface or abstract classes only and does not bring me to the second project's implementation classes. How can I get Eclipse to bring me to the implementation in this way?

I have tried adding project references in the project properties (both from the implementation project to the interface/abstract project and vice versa), but this didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Hold control, hover over the method name, and select "Open Implementation", or may be use F3 !!!

Comment: @NoobUnChained you haven't read the entire question. OP already knows how to do that...

Comment: have you tried Ctrl+T on a selected method or type ?

Comment: @A4L Yes, it works in a similar fashion; it only shows me the interfaces or abstract classes in the first (current) project.

Answer (score 0):

The first project does not have a reference of your second project to show you the implementations. If you want to see the implementations during control-click, you need to add the projects to your build path.

Comment: I don't want the second project to require the first to be in the build path as it's not really required (I have it reference the Jar that is the build product of the first as the only build dependency).

Comment: Also, the first project shouldn't have the second as a build requirement (it doesn't need or care about anything in that). It just uses the interfaces.

Comment: Then I don't think there is a way you can achieve this as the first project has no visibility of the second one. For the second project you have added a jar file with the abstract definitions, so first and second projects in eclipse are totally independent.

Comment: Well, yes, they are independent (I need them to be that way), but I'm hoping Eclipse has a property to make navigation links through the sources while I'm developing. I guess I can understand if this isn't the case as you say. It just makes things slightly less convenient for me.